# Observable subscribe content not executing

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

A submit button inside the component HTML triggers a function named `addCollaborators()`. The relevant code is below:

### component.ts

```
emails: string[] = [];

constructor(public userService: UserService) {}

// This is the function called from the HTML
addCollaborators() {
  this.emails.forEach(email => {
    const user = this.getUserFromEmail(email);
    if (user instanceof User) {
      this.counterService.someDbFunction();
    }
  });

  this.dialogRef.close();
}

getUserFromEmail(emailAddress: string): User | void {
  console.log("Code is reached here");
  this.userService.users$.subscribe((users: User[]) => {
    console.log("This is never reached");
    for (const user of users) {
      if ( /* Some boolean logic */ ) {
        return user;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

### user.service.ts

```
users$: Observable<User[]>;
```

As described in the log statements, none of the code within the subscription inside `getUserFromEmail` is executed. This is evident as none of the operations are carried out and the message is not present in the console. The `users$` observable is populated within the service constructor and subscribed to successfully in other places. In fact, this statement inside the constructor of `component.ts` is successful:

```
this.userService.users$.subscribe(users => console.log(users));
```

Let me know if any other information would be helpful and thanks ahead of time.

### Update

The following will not log anything, so it may be a more fundamental issue than previously thought.

```
addCollaborators() {
  console.log("I am logged");
  this.userService.users$.subscribe(users => console.log("I am not", users));
}
```

The relevant HTML:

```
<button mat-fab
        (click)="addCollaborators()"
        class="add-collaborators">
<mat-icon>group_add</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: if you are going to check the users, you will need to check them within the subscribe. remove the return user if statement, replace with the instanceof user if statement.

Comment: Even if I move all logic inside the subscribe, the operations are unable to complete. Updating question with more information and testing.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ls1ydv) here; Can you try extending this example with your code so that we see if you're getting any errors...

Kindly add **Error** & **Finally** block (like below) to your subscribe to see if there are any errors...

```
  getUserFromEmail(emailAddress: string): User | void {
    console.log("Code is reached here for "+ emailAddress);
    this.userService.users$().subscribe(

  /* DATA BLOCK */    
  (users: User[]) => 
  {
  console.log("This is never reached");
    for (const user of users) {
      /* if ( //Some boolean logic ) { return user; } */
    }
  } 
  /* ERROR BLOCK */    
  , errr => { console.log(errr); }
  /* FINALLY BLOCK */    
  , () => { console.log("this is the finally block");}
);
```

}

Comment: Adding the error and finally blocks yielded no additional logging. I will try to reproduce in the linked Stackblitz

Comment: adding error block will allow you to handle errors... adding a finally block is good practice